# Adding a javascript file to an already-running Java FX webengine

Tags: javascript, java, html, javafx-webengine

I have a Java application that is running a Java FX webengine (the end goal of all of this is to dynamically draw a D3.js plot). I'd like to be able to add new javascript files to it while it's already running, and then ideally unload them again when the javascript tells it to.

This has the effect of making some functionality available to the user or not (drawing certain features) without having to load all of the code in at once. It also helps me avoid future headaches with a forest of brittle if/then statements inside my javascript.

Question 1: Is "unloading" files from a running webengine even possible? At least, possible without redrawing the whole thing. I'm pretty sure that calling loadContent() with my new filepaths will make them available the way that I want, but I haven't come across anything talking about how you can remove existing source code from your HTML block.

Question 2: Any recommendations on how to elegantly approach feeding the extra sources into the webView? My thought process right now is stuck on brute force, but I haven't been even been able to brute force my way to a solution that works, so maybe I'm barking up the wrong tree.

Question 3: Is this even a good idea? It's possible to do this solely in the Javascript, but I want the appearance and disappearance of options directly tied to a java-side feature that's later going to be executed from the class Bridge, the same place I'm trying to load new content from right now.

I asked a lot of questions, but any help is appreciated!

Right now I am setting up the webengine's content like so:

```
final ResourceExtractor RESOURCE_EXTRACTOR
                = new ResourceExtractor(JavaScriptPlot.class);

    // prepare the local URI for d3.js
    final URI D3_JS_URI = RESOURCE_EXTRACTOR
            .extractResourceAsPath("d3.min.js")
            .toUri();

    // prepare the local URI for numeric.js
    final URI NUMERIC_JS_URI = RESOURCE_EXTRACTOR
            .extractResourceAsPath("numeric.min.js")
            .toUri();

    // prepare the local URI for topsoil.js
    final URI TOPSOIL_JS_URI = RESOURCE_EXTRACTOR
            .extractResourceAsPath("topsoil.js")
            .toUri();

    // build the HTML template (comments show implicit elements/tags)
    HTML_TEMPLATE = (""
            + "<!DOCTYPE html>\n"
            // <html>
            // <head>
            + "<style>\n"
            + "body {\n"
            + "  margin: 0; padding: 0;\n"
            + "}\n"
            + "</style>\n"
            // </head>
            + "<body>"
            + "<script src=\"" + D3_JS_URI + "\"></script>\n"
            + "<script src=\"" + NUMERIC_JS_URI + "\"></script>\n"
            + "<script src=\"" + TOPSOIL_JS_URI + "\"></script>\n"
            + "<script src=\"%s\"></script>\n" // JS file for plot
            // </body>
            // </html>
            + "").replaceAll("%20", "%%20");
```

The source path to replace %s is created here:

```
public class BasePlot extends JavaScriptPlot {

    private static final ResourceExtractor RESOURCE_EXTRACTOR
            = new ResourceExtractor(BasePlot.class);

    private static final String RESOURCE_NAME = "BasePlot.js";

    public BasePlot() {
        super(
                RESOURCE_EXTRACTOR.extractResourceAsPath(RESOURCE_NAME),
                new BasePlotDefaultProperties());
    }

}
```

And then later I take a file path already extracted as a resource, sourcePath, and insert it into the HTML block:

```
String buildContent() {
        return String.format(HTML_TEMPLATE, sourcePath.toUri());
}
```

Then I build my web view using the return value of buildContent()

```
private void initializeWebView() {
    runOnFxApplicationThread(() -> {
        // initialize webView and associated variables
        webView = new WebView();
        webView.setContextMenuEnabled(false);

        WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();

        webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(
                (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                    if (newValue == SUCCEEDED) {
                        if (new IsBlankImage().test(screenCapture())) {
                            webEngine.loadContent(buildContent());
                        }

                        topsoil = (JSObject) webEngine.executeScript("topsoil");
                        topsoil.setMember("bridge", new Bridge());
                    }
                });

        // asynchronous
        webEngine.loadContent(buildContent());
    });
}
```

And the Javascript can fire off the method in the class below to trigger the change. Right now it's manually creating a hardcoded resource, but once I work out once going wrong I'll make this part more elegant/logically organized.

```
//loads appropriate JS files into webview based on BasePlot's isotope type
public class Bridge {
        final URI ISOTOPE_URI = ISOTOPE_RESOURCE_EXTRACTOR
                .extractResourceAsPath("Concordia.js")
                .toUri();

        String finalHtml = buildContent().concat("<script src=\""+ISOTOPE_URI.toString()+"\"></script>\n");
        webView.getEngine().loadContent(finalHtml);
    }
}
```

The loadContent() above is giving me an application thread error: "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: topsoil"